# JQuery ScrollTop add/removeClass to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrolltop

I am struggling with I gues a simple thing. 
I try to make an element (phone img) fixed when user scrolls more than 600px, and make it unfixed again when he is at the end of this section. But it isn't fixed when he scrolls back to top. Why? what i am doing wrong?

Generally i am trying to make some transitions and animations inside of this phone conected to scroll event, some kind of tutorial how to use app.

Here is a codepen with my problem: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaGqRB?editors=1010 
and my ugly JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 584) {
      $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
    }if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
      $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');  
      $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');

   }
 });
```

css:

```
.phone-container{
position: relative;
top: 40px;  
}
.phone-container-fixed{
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
}
.phone-container-fixed-bot{
position: absolute;
top: 2420px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll back up, you probably want to remove the class you've added.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() <= 600) {
         $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
        $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
        $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');  
        $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css is overlapping. You have two ways:

Adding `!important` to your `phone-container-fixed`:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
        $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');         $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
    }
 });

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#output").html(windowTop);
});
```

```css
.one{
  postion: absolute;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.two{
  postion: absolute;
  height: 3000px;
  width: auto;
}
.phone-container{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;  
}
.phone-container-fixed{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50px !important;
}
.phone-container-fixed-bot{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2420px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
    <p id="output" style="position:fixed; left:20px; top:10px; padding:10px; font-weight:bold">
      You have scrolled the page by:
</div>
<div class="two">
    <div class="phone-container">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mpqaVH/phone_frame.png" alt="Phone frame">
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can remove the class `phone-container-fixed-bot` when scroll is lower than 2201 (you can add it to the first if condition):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
        $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
        $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');
        $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
    }
 });

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#output").html(windowTop);
});
```

```css
.one{
  postion: absolute;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.two{
  postion: absolute;
  height: 3000px;
  width: auto;
}
.phone-container{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;  
}
.phone-container-fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
.phone-container-fixed-bot{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2420px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
    <p id="output" style="position:fixed; left:20px; top:10px; padding:10px; font-weight:bold">
      You have scrolled the page by:
</div>
<div class="two">
    <div class="phone-container">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mpqaVH/phone_frame.png" alt="Phone frame">
    </div>
</div>
```

*The second one isn't the best solution (if-else statements), but you can work with this logic*

Comment: Thank you very much:) I must be tired, cause now i see it is pretty obvious :)

Comment: Sometimes the obvious isn't that obvious!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not removing the .phone-container-fixed-bot class when the user scrolls up..

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
          $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
        }if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
          $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');  
          $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');

       } if ($(window).scrollTop() < 2201) {
         $(".phone-container").removeClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
       }if ($(window).scrollTop() < 600) { 
         $(".phone-container").removeClass('phone-container-fixed');
       }
 });
```

Now this is dirty but you can also check if the div has a class before attempting to remove it.

```
if ($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to introduce the `else` part of the condition

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed');
  } else {
    $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed');
  }

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2201) {
    $('.phone-container').addClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
  } else {
    $('.phone-container').removeClass('phone-container-fixed-bot');
  }
});
```

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/EEgyGz)**